# Undefined Index in php with GET and POST

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, warnings, undefined

I have a php file say p1.php that is getting data from another php file say p2.php which is accessed in p1.php via $_GET. Now the data in $_GET is being saved in a variable $totPrice. p1.php also has a form that is referencing to itself and some processing is done with a MySql database. I am getting an error of:

```
"Notice: Undefined index: totP in C:\xampp\htdocs\fi\p1.php on line 'where ever $totPrice appears'".
```

Here's the code for p1.php:-

```
<?php
global $totPrice;
$totPrice = $_GET['totP'];
if(!isset($_COOKIE['username']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
$dbc      = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","authserver");
$username = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$ccno     = $_POST['ccno'];

    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($ccno))
{
     $query = "select * from authserver.fimembers where fName = '$username' AND     password_finmem=SHA('$password') AND CreditCard = $ccno";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1 )
{
$dbc1 = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fininsti");
$query1  = "select * from fininsti.fimembers where fName = '$username' AND    password_finmem=SHA('$password') AND CreditCard = $ccno"; 
    $result1 = mysqli_query($dbc1,$query1);
$row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result1,MYSQL_BOTH);
setcookie('username',$username,time()+60*60);
setcookie('ccno',$row[0],time()+60*60);
echo $totPrice.'<br />';
if($totPrice > $row[3])
if($_GET['totP'] > $row[3])
{
   $status = array('stat' => 0 );   // 0 = Not sufficient funds
}
else
{
$status = array('stat' => 1 );   // 1 = Good To Go!
$newAmt = $row[3]-$totPrice;
$query = "update fininsti.fimembers set Credit = $newAmt where CreditCard = $ccno";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc1,$query);
}           
$retMerUrl = "http://localhost/eTrans/site/confirm.php?".http_build_query($status);
setcookie('username',$username,time()-60*60);
setcookie('ccno',$row[0],time()-60*60);
mysqli_close($dbc1);
mysqli_close($dbc);
header('Location:'.$retMerUrl);             
}
else
   echo "Credentials don't match!";
}
else
{
    echo "Sorry! Fields empty!";
}
setcookie('userId',$username,time()-60*60);
setcookie('ccno',$row[0],time()-60*60);
mysqli_close($dbc);
}
}
?>
```

Please do get back to me if you have any problem with the question.

Comment: just a few other suggestions: use php session, never send password just by $_POST

Comment: Is totP in the URL of the page its hitting? The URL should look something like: p1.php?totP=5

Comment: ) AND CreditCard = $ccno"; i suggest CreditCard is a string so use ' ) AND CreditCard = '$ccno'";

Comment: Do you SERIOUSLY process credit card information with THIS code?

Comment: @CastroXXL Yeah that's how to URL is like.

Comment: @endo.anaconda The credit card is an integer, and do you suggest i send password using session variables.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Send password using session variables?

Answer (score 3):

You need to fix the first two lines:

```
global $totPrice;
$totPrice = $_GET['totP'];
```

1. Remove the first line. You do not need `global` outside of functions.
2. Replace the second line with this:

   ```
   $totPrice = isset($_GET['totP']) ? $_GET['totP'] : 0;
   ```
3. (not related to these two lines) **Fix the SQL injection issues in your code!!!**

Comment: 1)The thing is that the value of $totPrice comes from another page. So the solution apart form what you have suggested is :- <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?totP='.$_GET['totP'];?>" method="post">
2)Any suggestion to fix the SQL injection?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message(s) you are receiving, it's obvious that the `totP` is not being included in the URL the script is referencing. So your best bet is to include a few `isset` checks before referencing `$_GET` parameters, for example:

```
$totPrice = (isset($_GET['totP'])) ? $_GET['totP'] : null;
```

Also, not sure why you are making a `global` call, as you don't appear to be within a function.

Comment: The thing is that the value of $totPrice comes from another page. So the solution apart form what you have suggested is :- <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?totP='.$_GET['totP'];?>" method="post">

Answer (score 0):

To remove the notice a check with `isset($_GET['totP']` would do. If it is in the URL but not showing up in your page, make sure there is no rewriting happening.

You could always do `var_dump($_GET)` to see all of the information in the query params for the specific code.

It might be helpful to see what it is receiving for you to know whats wrong.